# WordPress WP_Query results not properly sorted by date?

Tags: php, sql, wordpress

I'm trying to sort all posts by date, using the following code:

```
  $args = array(
    'post_type' => array( 'post' ),
    'orderby' => 'date',
    // 'orderby' => 'post_date',
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
  );
  // wp_reset_query();
  $query = new wp_query( $args );

  while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();
    var_dump($query->post->post_date);
  endwhile;
```

Based on the above code, this is how results are now being output. Notice how the first four results are sorted, and starting from the fifth result it resorts again. How is that possible?

[HTML output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lpFAb.jpg)

I dumped the request, here's the SQL query: `SELECT wp_posts.* FROM wp_posts  WHERE 1=1  AND wp_posts.post_type = 'post' AND ((wp_posts.post_status = 'publish')) ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC`

When running the above query in the database, I get the following (properly sorted) results:

[DB SQL query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wCgvf.jpg)

At first I thought it must be some interfering plugin or code in `functions.php`. So I completely emptied the `functions.php` file and `disabled all plugins`, but the result remained the same.

I have no clue what's causing this, can anyone help me?

Comment: Can you do a `var_dump($query->posts);` before the while loop, and check if the posts still appear to be in the correct order at that point?

Comment: Same result. That's what I tried at first, but quickly noticed how the sorting was off. So I decided to dump only the `post_date` of each post, to make it more readable.

Comment: That is very weird. WordPress has hooks to modify the main query of a page - but as far as I know, those do not affect any queries you make yourself explicitly using `new wp_query`. And even if the query parameters got modified by anything outside – that should be reflected in the actual SQL code you got from dumping the whole query object then.

Comment: In case this starts getting stale, it may be worth moving over to https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/ and see if any of the folks over there might have some idea on this head scratcher.

Comment: Do you have any "sticky posts"?  I believe by default they get prepended to the query results.  You might try adding:  ignore_sticky_posts' => true

Comment: @DubVader You're a hero, that was the issue indeed. Thanks a million! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @DubVader, the issue was "sticky posts".

Problem solved by adding `'ignore_sticky_posts' => true` to the query arguments.